# Why is spring boot project showing red marker?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I made a new project from `https://start.spring.io/`.But when i used to import project 1 month ago there was no any error and any spring boot project used to run fine.But today I dont know what is wrong and I am seeing this:

[image]

Why is this error coming? I am using intelliJ and how can I solve this?

Comment: Just `Maven Refresh` or `Gradle Refresh` the project.

Comment: click on the hammer symbol to build the project in intellij

Comment: when i clicked on hammer then it is not able to build the project

Comment: my older projects are opening fine but when importing new project i am getting error?

Comment: i made na new project from intellij and such red markers are gone but when i make project from spring initializer unzip it and import it then it is showing me red markers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Invalidate the Cache and restart the IntelliJ.

> File > Invalidate Caches/ Restart > Click on Invalidate Caches Restart

After the restart, it takes time to reindex the project.

Comment: i made na new project from intellij and such red markers are gone but when i make project from spring initializer unzip it and import it then it is showing me red markers